# Compiling Error Use of unresolved identifier 'addButtonPressed'

Tags: swift

When I go to compile I get:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'addButtonPressed'

I have the UIKit imported so I don't really understand why I am getting this error. The error shows up here:

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonPressed(_:)))
```

Here is the whole code.

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(addButtonPressed(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    }

    func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Item", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `addButtonPressed(_:)` doesn't match your actual method of `addButtonPressed(sender:)`.

Change one to match the other.

You can change the selector to either:

```
#selector(addButtonPressed)
```

or

```
#selector(addButtonPressed(sender:))
```

Note that if you have multiple `addButtonPressed` methods with different parameters then you can't use that 1st selector option, you need to use the 2nd one that includes the parameters.

Or you can leave the selector as-is and change your method to:

```
func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```

Regardless of the change you make, you also need to add `@objc` to the function.

```
@objc func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```